# How to enable audio scrubber in iOS Lock Screen control panel?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I have the following dictionary for MPNowPlayingInfoCenter

```
@{MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle: @"First Title",
                                MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Album-Cover.jpg"]],
                                MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.storyAudioPlayer.duration],
                                MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.storyAudioPlayer.currentTime],
                                MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate:@1.0
                                }
```

Everything else is working fine but I can't seek songs using the slider. As shown in the image. What parameter am I missing?

[image: Lock screen screenshot]

Comment: Was there a trick you had to do to get the buttons to work in iOS 7? The double-tap-home-audio-controls work fine for me in iOS 6, but the Control Center buttons don't send events to my app in iOS 7. There's a thread on the developer forums where people are saying this seems to be an iOS 7 bug. Thanks.

Comment: Have you figured out how to do this (scrubber)?

Comment: @Tenfour04 no.. just adding   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
 in viewDidAppear seems to work for me

Comment: @SG1 nope :|

You are looking for the same?

Comment: Actually, I found that it only doesn't work on my Verizon iPhone 5. It doesn't work for any third party apps on that phone. Works fine on all my other test devices. I have a feeling that this scrubber has not been enabled for third-party apps, since nothing related to it has been added to the constants for the remote control events.

Comment: I have another (possibly dumb!) question: I'm using `AVAudioPlayer` and I've implemented the remote controls with `UIEventTypeRemoteControl`. Do I have to use `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` to display the duration and title?

Also, for seeking the time, are you happy to use those two `<<` and `>>` buttons? I've got them working! :D

Comment: @AshishAwaghad did you managed to find out yet ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You could file a bug report to Apple so that they implement it someday.

EDIT: It's now possible to do it since iOS 9

Comment: no u can, there is an 3rd party app called HABU that allows you to seek. I am also looking for answer on how to do it. https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/habu-music/id540535146?mt=8

Comment: @Desmond that app is using the Music app to play its music. It's a completely different thing and the music needs to already be in the library.

Comment: HI @lap.flix,

you are right, i checked the app and other app like spotify, they are using different controller.

Comment: @desmond If it's important for you you could fill a feature request on Apple's bug reporter tool. The more duplicates they get the more priority you get (it's a weird system but that,s how they roll and it's sort of logic)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it on iOS 9.1 and higher with help of MPRemoteCommandCenter and changePlaybackPositionCommand.

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40075870/1549699)

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**

You can do it with `MPRemoteCommandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand`.

> The command object for changing the playback position in a media item.

```
let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
    commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand.addTarget { event in
        if let event = event as? MPChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent {
            let time = CMTime(seconds: event.positionTime, preferredTimescale: 1000000)
            self.avplayer.seekTo(time)
        }
        return .success
    }
```