# How to change track position on lock screen/control center?

Tags: ios, ios7, remote-control, control-center

When playing a song with the ios 7 music app the user can use slider to change song position in the lock screen/the control center. Slider is active:

[image]

But when playing music in my app user can't do it. Slider isn't active:

[image]

How can i enable these feature in my app?

Comment: How are you playing music in your app?

Comment: @WDUK via MPMoviePlayerController

Comment: @NeimanAleksei how do you show the song title and song duration ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change track position with help of MPRemoteCommandCenter on iOS  9.1 and higher.

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_0) {
            MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
            [commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand setEnabled:true];
            [commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(changedThumbSliderOnLockScreen:)];
        }
```

and method

```
- (MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus)changedThumbSliderOnLockScreen:(MPChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent *)event
{
    // change position
    [self setCurrentPlaybackTime:event.positionTime];
    // update MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime
    [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];

    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

**swift4**
You can change track position with help of MPRemoteCommandCenter on iOS  9.1 and higher.

```
let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand.isEnabled = true
commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand.addTarget(
 self, action:#selector(changePlaybackPositionCommand(_:)))
```

**and method**

```
@objc func changePlaybackPositionCommand(_ event:
          MPChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
    let time = event.positionTime
    //use time to update your track time
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus.success
}
```

Note that you have to do that for every command in `commandCenter` if you want that commend to be enabled.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for the same thing but I don't think this is possible see this post:

[How to enable audio scrubber in iOS Lock Screen control panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941268/how-to-enable-audio-scrubber-in-ios-lock-screen-control-panel)

Also popular apps like Spotify and Soundcloud don't have this implemented.

If you are looking for a way to show the current music on the lock screen you need to do the following.

First when you play a new track update the NowPlayingInfo :

```
NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [songInfo setObject:trackTitle forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    [songInfo setObject:artistName forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    [songInfo setObject:duration forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
    [songInfo setObject:releaseDate forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyReleaseDate];
    [songInfo setValue:playbackRate forKey:MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate];
    [songInfo setObject:elapsedTime forKey:MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime];
    [songInfo setObject:albumArtImage forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
    [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];
```

To handle events from the Lockscreen, you first need to tell your app to start receiving events from the remote control. I do this in the  application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of my AppDelegate using the following code

```
 // Turn on remote control event delivery
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

Next you need to implement remoteControlReceivedWithEvent method to handle the captured events. In APPDelegate add the following method

```
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)receivedEvent {

 if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {

    switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
            //pause code here
            break;

        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
             //play code here
            break;

        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:
            // previous track code here
            break;

        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
            //next track code here
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
 }
```

}

More info on MPNowPlayingInfoCenter from the apple docs ->  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class

Comment: How can I use `remoteControlReceivedWithEvent ` ?

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia in swift :
override func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {
        switch event?.subtype {
        case .remoteControlPlay: print("")
        default: break
        }
    }