# Lock screen player's seek bar issue in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, audio-player

If I play music through iPhone's native music player in iOS 7 and access it on lock screen then I can drag the player's seek bar i.e user can interact with it.

Screenshot :

[image]

But if I play music from my app which supports background audio play then the player's seek bar user interaction is disabled on lock screen. I am unable to move it.

Screenshot :

[image]

I searched apple's documentation but didn't find anything related to this.

My question is, does iOS allow 3rd party apps to interact with player's seek bar on lock screen like native music app or do I have to add some setting for it in my code ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18979132

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve my problem :(

Comment: I had same problem, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40075870/2961534) will help you to do that.

Comment: I found solution for slider here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48890827/9359678 Hope this will help you.

Comment: I found solution for playback position slider over here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48890827/9359678 hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. but as per my findings ,iOS does not allow third party apps to interact with lock screen seek bar. Though, there is no official information about it.

Comment: @iVipS I don't find way to solve this, I think iOS just don't permit to have this.

Comment: It does. Check Netflix app for iOS.